# How to adjust fancyvrb verbatiminput text to fit inside tabularx cell

Tags: tabularx, fancyvrb

I would like to include text from file into tabularx cell but got two issues:

- verbatiminput text overflow defined margins
- The cell has extra vertical margins

How I may fix this ?

[image: capture]

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
inner= 1.5cm,
outer= 3cm,
top = 2cm,
bottom = 3cm,
bindingoffset = 0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set Arial as default

\RecustomVerbatimCommand{\VerbatimInput}{VerbatimInput}
{
 fontfamily = courier,
 fontsize = \footnotesize,
 frame = single,
 vspace = 0pt,
 framesep = 0pt,
 framerule = 0.5pt,
 rulecolor=\color{red},
 baselinestretch = 0.2
}
    
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{8DB3E2}A table} \\
        \toprule
            cmd arg $--$switch1 $--$switch2 $--$switch3 $--$switch4 $--$paramY  999 &
            \blindtext \\
        \midrule
            cmd2 &
            \VerbatimInput{files/f1.txt}
            \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx} 
    \vspace{1pt}
    \newline    

\end{document}
```

f1 file

```
Paper size: 4L
Ink capacicy: 0.5oz 

The random-option changes the default blind text to a sequence of predefined
sentences. The next paragraph starts with the next phrase from the previous
paragraph.
# $ % & ~ _ ^ \ { }
```

Comment: Your input file does not seem to have any problematic characters. Maybe include it as normal text with typewriter font/obeylines instead of verbatim?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Real text contains latex reserved characters. That is the reason to use verbatim. (passwords) and not `\input{file}`

Comment: verbatim means no automatic line breaking, so either you need a much smaller font, or you want a wider column, or if lines in the source do not need to be preserved, you do not want verbatim. What output do you want?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle same output as 1st row, 2nd col. but printing special characters. `\input{file}` does not works.

Comment: just use `\catcode\`\\=12 \catcode\`\{=12 \catcode\`\}=12 \input{file}`  making as many characters safe as you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [package `listings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) to input the varbatim text with automatic line breaks. In the following example, I've limited line breaks to whitespaces:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
Paper size: 4L
Ink capacicy: 0.5oz 

The random-option changes the default blind text to a sequence of predefined
sentences. The next paragraph starts with the next phrase from the previous
paragraph.
# $ % & ~ _ ^ \ { }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
inner= 1.5cm,
outer= 3cm,
top = 2cm,
bottom = 3cm,
bindingoffset = 0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Set Arial as default

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,breaklines=true,breakatwhitespace=true}
    
\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X X}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{8DB3E2}A table} \\
        \toprule
            cmd arg $--$switch1 $--$switch2 $--$switch3 $--$switch4 $--$paramY  999 &
            \blindtext \\
        \midrule
            cmd2 &
            \lstinputlisting[frame=single,rulecolor=\color{red},aboveskip=-\baselineskip,belowskip=-\baselineskip]{\jobname.txt}
            \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx} 
    \vspace{1pt}
    \newline    

\end{document}
```

[image: using listings]

There are a lot of more options, e.g., to show automatic line breaks.